# Complexity analysis of convex optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization, computational-complexity

I am studying an optimization problem

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}^*=\text{argmax}\quad\sum_{d=1}^{D}\log(\mathbf{a}_d^T\mathbf{x}+b)+\mathbf{c}_d^T\mathbf{x}+f_d\\
\text{subject to}\quad \mathbf{f}_k^T\mathbf{x}+g_k\ge0\qquad k=1,\ldots,K\\0\preceq\mathbf{x}\preceq1
\end{equation}

where all the bold-faced letters are $D\times1$ vectors and $\preceq$ is element-wise inequality.

I used MATLAB cvx solver SeDuMi to solve the problem but I am stuck at the computational complexity analysis. I can't find a proper reference. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You do *not* want to use CVX's algorithms as a basis for complexity analysis in this case. I use an [unproven hack](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/advanced.html#the-successive-approximation-method) to handle the log function, which SeDuMi and other SDP solvers like it cannot handle natively. That said, SDPT3 does have support for logarithms in the objective, which CVX does not actually take advantage of. Perhaps [the SDPT3 home page](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~mattohkc/sdpt3.html) has papers that will help you.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer. Let's say -for the sake of the argument- that the appropriate solver is used, not necessarily cvx. Do you know any reference discussing this type of problems and the complexity of its solution -in general- ? 

P.S. I edited the question because I forgot to write the sum in the objective function.

Comment: through some research, I have known that the computational complexity of interior point methods is $O(m*ln(1/\epsilon))$ where m is the problem size and epsilon is the required accuracy. But this is only applicable for LP and QP problems, which the problem at hand is not!! I cannot find any proper reference for convex nonlinear problems other than the famous QP and SDP ones.